# grep each line in a file

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have two files: one is a fairly long collection of names (names.txt), and another file (grades.csv) which is a huge file of names and the corresponding grades. I would like to iterate over each line in names.txt and extract that name in grades.csv with the entire matching line.

This is how a small sample names.txt looks like

```
"Dumbledore, Albus"
"Potter, Harry"
"Riddle, Tom
```

Here is the structure of a dummy grades.csv file

```
"Granger, Hermione", 96.65%, 9,10
"Mcgonagall, Minerva", 80.43%, 6,7
"Dumbledore, Albus", 100%, 8, 9
"Potter, James", 91%, 7,89
"Ravenclaw, Rowena", 32%, 4,56
"Potter, Harry", 34%, 56,67
"Riddle, Tom", 99%, 3,4
```

I'd like to extract each line of names.txt and search grades.csv to get this

```
"Dumbledore, Albus", 100%, 8, 9
"Potter Harry", 34%, 56,67
"Riddle Tom", 99%, 3,4
```

I know I would have to use grep/awk/sed for this (I am using a Linux environment) but I don't know how to use grep to loop over the lines in a file, since I am not very good at the bash command terminal. Any help appreciated!

Comment: The answer seem to be `grep -f` , but the question is so specific that other people won't be able to use the answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I made some changes to your `names.txt` and `grades.csv` - some of the names are comma-separated and some aren't. I removed commas within quotes, so here are the new files:

```
22:46 $ cat names.txt 
"Dumbledore Albus"
"Potter Harry"
"Riddle Tom"

22:46 $ cat grades.csv 
"Granger Hermione", 96.65%, 9,10
"Mcgonagall Minerva", 80.43%, 6,7
"Dumbledore Albus", 100%, 8, 9
"Potter James", 91%, 7,89
"Ravenclaw Rowena", 32%, 4,56
"Potter Harry", 34%, 56,67
"Riddle Tom", 99%, 3,4
```

You can use `grep` with a file argument `-f`:

```
22:46 $ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash
names="/path/to/names.txt"
grades="/path/to/grades.csv"
grep -f <(tr ',' '\n' < "${names}") "${grades}"
```

This gives me the following output:

```
22:46 $ ./script.sh 
"Dumbledore Albus", 100%, 8, 9
"Potter Harry", 34%, 56,67
"Riddle Tom", 99%, 3,4
```

**EDIT**

Assuming the `names.txt` and `grades.csv` as a rule are formatted as "Lastname, Firstname" case-insensitively:

```
#!/bin/bash
names="/path/to/names.txt"
grades="/path/to/grades.csv"
grep -fi "${names}" "${grades}"
```

Comment: @ erip thanks! I'll try this out. Yes the commas were supposed to be there in grades.csv I did not add them initially. Have made the edit.

Comment: @ erip How would you modify your grep command in this case? when the commas are indeed in as in the original format?

Comment: @ erip. Yes Thanks! The search should also be case insensitive. In that case all I need to do is add the -i flag to the grep search right?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
  while read l; do grep -i "${l//\"/}" grades.csv; done < names.txt
```

I tested it with `bash` on Ubuntu 14.04. The output:

```
$ while read l; do grep -i "${l//\"/}" grades.csv; done < names.txt 
"Dumbledore, Albus", 100%, 8, 9
"Potter, Harry", 34%, 56,67
"Riddle, Tom", 99%, 3,4
```

Comment: This runs a separate grep for each line of the input file.  `grep` has an option to take multiple patterns from an input file, one per line, so erip's answer using that is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question literally:

```bash
for each in `cat names.txt`; do
    grep -q $each grades.csv
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for novelty...
If you didn't have commas in the name strings then you could also achieve this using the unix **join** operator.

`man join`

> The join utility performs an **equality join** on the specified files and writes the result to the standard output.

If both inputs are sorted (in this example the files are re-written)

```sh
$ sort -b -o names.txt names.txt
$ sort -b -o grades.txt grades.txt
```

then you can do the following

```sh
$ join -t ',' grades.txt names.txt
"Dumbledore Albus", 100%, 8, 9
"Potter Harry", 34%, 56,67
"Riddle Tom", 99%, 3,4
```

The `-t` flag tells `join` to use the character as a field delimiter for both input and output.